# unable to write having clause with group by clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having

i want to show the daily fan running hours consumption with in particular dates. im able to get the records with out between the dates while writing the having clause to get the records between dates getting error.

> Column 'DeviceTimeStamp' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

sql query

```
    SELECT 
    CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) as Date,
    round(MAX(CAST([Fan1Hrs] as float))-MIN(CAST([Fan1Hrs] as float)),2) as Units
    FROM RawData
    where DeviceImei = '81'
    GROUP BY CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE)
    having DeviceTimeStamp > '2020-03-23' and DeviceTimeStamp < '2020-03-23' 
    ORDER BY CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) desc
```

Comment: `HAVING` is a step that is run AFTER your `GROUP BY` is run. So the result set that exists after `GROUP BY` doesn't have a column `DeviceTimeStamp`. Change that to  `HAVING [Date] > '2020-03-23' and DeviceTimeStamp < '2020-03-23'` and it should clear it up.

Comment: got solution , having CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) > '2020-03-23' and CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) < '2020-03-28'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) as Date,
    round(MAX(CAST([Fan1Hrs] as float))-MIN(CAST([Fan1Hrs] as float)),2) as Units
    FROM RawData
   where DeviceImei = '81'
   GROUP BY CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE)
   having CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) > '2020-03-23' and CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) < '2020-03-28'
   ORDER BY CAST([DeviceTimeStamp] AS DATE) desc
```